# Getting the envelope of a signal using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, envelope

(person me in advance, I'm an absolute beginner in Matlab).

I have an issue using the envelope fonction in Matlab.
My goal is to get the up and down envelope of a signal, in order to have the length of the variation of my signal, in function of the time. I tried to use the envelope function already integrated in Matlab, but it looks like I don't get something.

The data I'm using is taken from a txt file which look like this.

[Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehdhP.png)
[txt of the signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNwuP.png)

I tried to copy an existing program but I think that I haven't understood it perfectly.
Here is the code I have inspired myself to make this program.

```
clc;
%Extraction des données du fichier
load signal.txt signal;
t = signal(:,1); % Abscisse : temps (s)
y = signal(:,2); % Ordonnée : pression (mmHg)

%Tracé du signal original
figure(1);
plot(t,y,'b-'); 
title('Signal à analyser','FontSize',18);

%Extraction de l'enveloppe
[up,down] = envelope(t,y,'linear');

%tracé de l'enveloppe
figure(2)
plot(t,up); hold on;
plot(t,down);
title('Enveloppe du signal','FontSize',18);
hold off;
```

This code is working for a file "data" included with the program, but doesn't work with mine.
[The file "data" it works with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtG97.png)

With my signal, it shows the following error :
[The error I get with the data of my signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHzvC.png)
I give you the code I wrote, to make it easier to you to understand what my mistake is.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please specify what you mean by "envelope" of the signal, and more specifically what the desrired result would be for the signal you provide. To me, an envelope is the amplitude of a modulated signal (see first image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves))), but that does not seem to be the case here, so what do you mean by "envelope"?

Comment: The image you show is the result I want to get. My goal is to have the length between the top envelope and the bottom envelope, in order to analyse my signal (blood pressure(t)=> if the "length I'm talking about is large enough, the pressure is between the diastolic pressure and the systolic pressure).